# Why can't I use a future blockhash for on-chain randomness?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, blockhash, hashing, random

To my knowledge, Blockhashes are determined by the hash of numerous things involving the instruction data of the transactions involved in the block, and the previous hashes.

it is practically impossible to guess the instruction data of all transactions involved in a specific block.

given that, if I set a seed as the hash of a slot greater than `1 minute into the future` and `less than 2 minutes 30seconds into the future`, then why won't I be able to use the indeterministic nature of these transaction data as a source of randomness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A malicious leader can front-run your transaction by grinding the blockhash, including whatever ordered set of transactions required.

It doesn't matter how in the future your blockhash is, a malicious leader can choose to win by manipulating the blockhash.